# Apple Passkit: use NFC to open an URL

Tags: nfc, passkit

I successfully created a pass with PassKit. But I want to add NFC capability to this pass to, when other smartphone (NFC reader) read the card, an URL will be opened to this smartphone.

I don't know if I need to do an NFC Certificate request for Apple Pay, because I don't want to use NFC for Apple Pay (https://developer.apple.com/contact/passkit/) ?

Can I achieve this without a certificate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you absolutely must have a certificate authorizing the use of NFC even if it is not a payment.

To obtain a certificate, contact Apple: http://developer.apple.com/contact/passkit.

But they rarely answer

Comment: Do you think that, with this certificate, I can use NFC on Wallet to just open an URL on other device with NFC reader ?
Apple developer documentation says thats we need an Apple Pay NFC Reader to read Wallet NFC content, so what about a classic NFC reader ?

Comment: No you can't, NFC feature in Wallet send a payload (usually a unique identifier), not a command, but you can create an app on other device witch open an URL with the payload. But I don't think Wallet meets your use case